# R how to retrieve data from data.frame with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am wondering how to perform some basic data manipulation in R. What i want to do is the following.

I have a data table with the following pattern :

```
  V1     V2     V3    
  ABC     X     24
  ABC     Y     30
  EFG     X     4
  EFG     Y     28
  HIJ     P     40
  HIJ     Y     41
  PKL     X     32
```

1. Now i want to retrieve all the values/pairs of V1 where it doesn't have a corresponding value which is not X on V2. In the above dataset this subset would be

   ```
   HIJ     P    40
   HIJ     Y    41
   ```

Since neither of the pair of HIJ have a V2 value of X.

2. I would also like to retrieve all values of V1 that don't repeat twice. In the above example it would be

   ```
   PKL  X 32
   ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mentioned `data.table`, so here's two possible approaches for both requests

```
library(data.table)
```

For 1.

```
setDT(df)[, .SD[all(V2 != "X")], by = V1]
#     V1 V2 V3
# 1: HIJ  P 40
# 2: HIJ  Y 41
```

For 2.

```
df[, .SD[.N == 1L], by = V1]
#     V1 V2 V3
# 1: PKL  X 32
```

Or (a bit more optimized version)

```
indx <- df[, .(indx = .I[.N == 1L]), by = V1]$indx
df[indx]
#     V1 V2 V3
# 1: PKL  X 32
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `dplyr` if you decide to work on a `data.frame`

```
library(dplyr)

# Problem 1
df %>% group_by(V1) %>% filter(all(V2 != "X"))

#    V1 V2 V3
# 1 HIJ  P 40
# 2 HIJ  Y 41

# Problem 2
df %>% group_by(V1) %>% filter(n() == 1)

#    V1 V2 V3
# 1 PKL  X 32
```

if your data is

```
V1 <- c("ABC", "ABC", "EFG", "EFG", "HIJ", "HIJ", "PKL")
V2 <- c("X", "Y", "X", "Y", "P", "Y", "X")
V3 <- c(24,30,4,28,40,41,32)
df <- data.frame (V1,V2,V3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume your data is in a `data.frame` called `foo`.

For 1. I like `by()`. `by` all entries of `V1` look whether `"X"` is `%in%` the corresponding entries of `V2`. Wrap this in `names()` and `which()`.

```
hits <- names(which(with(foo,by(V2,V1,function(xx)!"X"%in%xx))))
foo[foo$V1 %in% hits,]
   V1 V2 V3
5 HIJ  P 40
6 HIJ  Y 41
```

For 2. This is even simpler:

```
names(which(table(foo$V1)<2))
[1] "PKL"
```